# Wordpress throwing "Destination folder already exists." when creating child theme

Tags: wordpress

I have a very simple Child Theme

->my-theme
     ->style.css

```
/*
  Theme Name:     My Child Theme
  Theme URI:      google.com
  Description:    My Child Theme
  Author:         person
  Author URI:     google.com
  Template:       Landscape
  Version:        1.0.3
*/

@import url("../landscape/style.css");
```

But when I try to install it I see...

```
Unpacking the package…

Installing the theme…

This theme requires a parent theme. Checking if it is installed…

Preparing to install Landscape 1.0.3…

Downloading install package from https://wordpress.org/themes/download/landscape.1.0.3.zip…

Unpacking the package…

Installing the theme…

Destination folder already exists. /home/<site>/public_html/site/wp-content/themes/landscape/

Theme install failed.

Theme installed successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

Template name should be landscape

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/problems-with-child-theme